# Offline support for Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

If users could read items which they engaged when even they are offline, it would be a very useful experience. Suppose there is a user with limited time internet connectivity, so he can sync his stack exchange stuff to his phone while he is in the internet connection. Then he would be able to read them. After he wrote an answer it should be saved in his phone. Then once he connected to internet that answer should be published automatically.